# AngularJS Radio button binging to the JSON array and submissiom

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to angularJS. 
I have a requirement as below:

1. Pull the student objects from DB.
2. Show all the objects in the UI with radio buttons.
3. User can select on of the radio button and submit the form.
4. On the submission, I want to sent the selected student object to service method.

I have pulled all the student objects from the DB. Please help on binding radio button to each of the student objects.
Also how can I send the particular selected student object on to the service method? Please help!!!!!

This is the controller getting student details:

```
mainApp.controller("viewStudentController", function($scope, $http) {
    var resData = {};
    $scope.student = {};
    var url = "/webservice-1.0/rest/student/"+$scope.id;

    $http.get(url)
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.student = angular.fromJson(response.data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Include the the code which you have

Comment: @devo I have added the controller code which pull the student values from DB.

Comment: You should implement your html as well and if stuck then ask question, IMHO

Comment: @JitheshGopinathan you should post your html and js code which is related to your question.

Comment: can you paste what "response.data" return to you?

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Xsk5X/1819/ . Is this what you want?

Comment: in the question he said pull student object that mean we have 1 student with n options, i think!!

Comment: @riteshmeher I was looking for something like that. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Maher Actually what I meant was getting all the student objects from DB, that is an array of student objects. The above example provided by ritishmeher might work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add ng-model to your radio button input and bind it using variable defined in controller.

```
 <li ng-repeat="n in names">
      <label>{{n.name}}
        <input type="radio" **ng-model="$parent.name"** name="name" value="{{n.name}}"           required />
      </label>
 </li>
```

I added a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/riteshmeher/05L75g92/). It might help you.